# how to read teamspeak3 server log files

Tags: php, logging, server

Hi I have a question about how do I read TeamSpeak 3 Server files in PHP read file.

The files is named "ts3server_2015-11-24__12_06_56.467055_3.log" where the last number is the teamspeak id "3" so how do I read the all the files ordered by the dates and the last number that is 3 should be a variable. and the files is placed in a directory called /logs

Hope anyone can help me with this :)

Here is a screenshot of some of the files on there:

http://i.imgbox.com/GIrTM5Xm.png

Comment: What did you try so far? Asking "please write my code for me" is not the purpose of questions on SO. If you try to rephrase your question to *what you are actually trying to do*, like "how can I list all files in a folder in PHP", you will find already-existing questions that will get you started.

Comment: I did not write anything, because I dont know how to read the files :(

Answer (score 1):

In very basic form you could do something like this - you will need to adapt it to suit your needs but it should give you a good starting point on which to build.

```
<?php

        $dir=realpath( '/volume1/homes/admin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/logs' );

        function filter( &$item ){
            $item=preg_replace( '@[^0-9]@', '', pathinfo( $item, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
        }

        if( $dir ){

            /* Add all .log files to an array */
            $files=glob( $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.log' );

            /* Sort the log files by filtering non integers */
            $keys=$files;
            array_walk( $keys, 'filter' );

            /* Add the integers as keys and then sort */
            $files=array_combine( $keys, $files );
            ksort( $files, SORT_NUMERIC );


            /* loop through the array */
            foreach( $files as $file ){

                /* read the log file - as array */
                $lines=file( $file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );

                /* Process your log file, line by line */
                foreach( $lines as $line ){
                    echo $line.'<br />';
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try that :)